# issue with jquery post in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some code that gets data from server side:

```
$.post("<%=getFavoritesUrl%>?r="+(Math.random() * 999) ,{"data":null},function(response){
    *do stuff here*
})
.fail(function(response){
    console.log("FailText: " + response.responseText);  
});
```

The server code looks like this:

```
        db = getDatabaseConnection();
        object = new JSONObject();

        if(db != null){
            Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(getStmt);

            while(rs.next()){
                object.put(rs.getString("PACKAGE_NAME"), rs.getString("DISPLAY_NAME"));
            }
        }

      writer.write(favorites.toString());
      writer.flush();
```

All of this works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in IE. the fail callback in my jquery post just prints the object that I send in the response, for instance:

```
FailText: {"wwskoacc.P_ReDirectViewBill":"View Your Billing Statement"}
```

I've been scratching my head on this all morning and I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using IE11

Comment: which IE are you talking about?

Comment: IE11. Edited my question.

Comment: the `fail()` handler is hit if the server responds with anything other than `200 OK`. Check the console to see what the response is, and hopefully an error message you can diagnose.

Comment: Side note - Not really sure why you are appending a random integer to a POST method.

Comment: The random integer was because some people said that IE caches aggressively, which can cause errors. That was the attempted fix. And no errors on fail. It just spits out the json I'm returning in the response.

Comment: could you try to post any non null data? an empty string maybe

Comment: an try to invoke a complete $.ajax?